# How do you change the author link of an article on Google scholar?

Tags: google-scholar

In my list of article suggestions on google scholar, I can click on the name of an author, and I am link to the page of someone having the same name as the author but on another topic. The true author with the same name also has a page on google scholar, and the article appears, with exactly the same reference.
It turns out that the author is my PhD student and so I would like to help this person to update, but I do not see how. It would be better if the link from the article goes to the right author and not to the other one. Is asking the "false author" to remove the article from the list or asking directly google scholar the only options? Is there no way to say that people are authors of articles like for researchgate?